# How can I move the header image position on mobile device

Tags: html, css

Hi Can you please help me how can I move the "Book online" image button below the header on mobile devices.

Web site http://centralfloridaorthodontic.com/

Comment: I can't help you unless you give us your HTML and CSS

Comment: Hi RHShanks92 I tried Wizzzard code but it doesn't work Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First put your css to a css-stylesheet or something else and add a class to your element, **I RECOMMEND: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp**

```
<div class="mybutton" style="text-align: right;margin: 0px 50px 15px 5px;max-width:100%;"><a href...
```

Then use the @media rule to set css only for mobile sizes:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .mybutton {
        margin: 15px 15px 15px 5px;
    }
}
```

Comment: like RHShanks92 said before, we need a concrete example of your issue